# Not able to uninstall NVM packages

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed NodeJs in root user.When I tried to install it in sudo user, but i was not able to Install Nodejs. I was able to remove the npm packages. I am not able to remove NVM packages. So please help me to uninstall NVM packages from root user.

Answer (score 1):

Note for the next installation: if it seems that cannot run nvm, try to close the terminal, and reopen it again.

To uninstall nvm from root try:

`$ rm -rf /root/.nvm`
Then edit `/root/.bashrc` file, find the following lines and delete them:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
[[ -r $NVM_DIR/bash_completion ]] && \. $NVM_DIR/bash_completion
```

If there is no `/root/.nvm` directory, then you need to figure out where did you install nvm. Find an `.nvm` directory, and delete it.